# Visual Studio 2017 can't inspect STL containers in objects from statically linked library

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2017

I have a weird problem that might come from how I build my library but I'm looking for some help here.
I have some code that I use accross multiple programs so I packaged it in a library. Some objects in the library use containers. 
I want to be able to inspect the content of these objects in visual studio while debugging.

One of those objects the "Scene" contains a

```
map<std::string,map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<VertexBufferObject>>>
```

but when I inspect it it is really hard to read
[instead of a nice view I have this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vmw0G.png)

```
map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<Shader>>
```

with the similar problem

But for exemple the scene salso has a

```
map<std::string,std::shared_ptr<Texture>>
```

and the output in the debugger inspector is nice:

[inspector here desplays things nicely](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jELih.png)

I am not sure of the origin of this, i don't know very well how the inspector works so I have a hard time diagnosing this.  Is it because of the way I built my library? I have a debug library and a release library for both types of builds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If any one ends up with the same issue, I corrected it by using the option /DEBUG:FULL in the linker of my program. Some things needed for natvis would be optimized out.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution, you could mark it as answer.